# Checkbox issue in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

There are 2 checkboxes. If select both corresponding frame value will run. But after selecting both, if I deselect 1box and play, its not playing the selected object's frame. Please provide solution as soon as possible.

Comment: Thnx for ur reply. We found the solution

Comment: then you can answer your own question, it could help anyone in future facing same. :)